# How it is possible that display results change even no transfromation are run between?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have weird issue with in Databricks environment. 
I am trying to do some debugging but the display results are not consistent with the code. The display results change even there is nothing run in between the display (df.filter[df[col]=='value'])

Have anyone encountered this kind of thing before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a certain `shuffle` happening and your earlier transformations are redone since the dataframe isn't persisted in your databricks environment. Try `df.persist()` and then try `display()` 2 times?

Comment: Hi, this works! Big thanks :). Btw is there a specific situation when this shuffle happens?

Comment: All transformations go through shuffles. it is essentially how spark works.